# Image manipulation: Import stills from video into python/matplotlib?

Tags: python, video, image-processing, numpy, matplotlib

I am playing with stacking and processing astronomical photographs.  I'm as interested in understanding algorithms as I am in the finished images, so I have not (yet) tried any of the numerous polished products floating around.

I have moderately-sized collections of still photographs (dozens at a time) which I can successfully import using

```
img = imread("filename.jpg")
```

This produces a `numpy` `ndarray` matrix, which I can manipulate using the tools available from `numpy` and `scipy.ndimage`, and display using `imshow()`.  This is supported on the back end by the [Python Imaging Library, PIL](http://effbot.org/zone/pil-index.htm), which as far as I can tell supports only still images.

For longer exposures, it'd be nice to set my camera to take video, then extract frames from the video and run them through the same analysis pipeline as the still images.  As far as I can tell, PIL supports only still images.  My camera produces Quicktime movies with `.MOV` file extensions.

Is there a Python library that will let me access the data from frames of a video?

Alternatively, I'd appreciate guidance on using an external tool (there seems to exist a command-line `ffmpeg`, but I haven't tried it) to generate temporary files that I can feed into my still-image pipeline.  Since I might want to examine all 18k frames in a ten-minute, 30fps movie, just extracting all the frames into one big folder is probably not an option.

I am running Python 2.7 on OSX Mavericks; I have easy access to MacPorts to install things.

Comment: Hmmm, now I see [this](http://zulko.github.io/blog/2013/09/27/read-and-write-video-frames-in-python-using-ffmpeg/), which seems to do the commandline ffmpeg through a pipe.

Comment: As a spamy answer, see https://github.com/soft-matter/pims.  The project you link to has issues if you want to extract a specific frame.  For a better sense of the issues that ffmpeg presents see https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/pull/850 and linked discussion.

Answer (score 1):

The following line of ffmpeg will let you extract 10 seconds of video, starting at a prespecified time (here 20 seconds after the start of the movie) :

```
ffmpeg -i myvideo.MOV -ss 00:00:20.00 -t 10 img%3d.jpg
```

It is easy to figure out how you can use that in a Bash loop or run the command in a loop via Python.